# Trying to include Node JS libraries in 3rd Party Application

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to use the below node.js modules in a 3rd party application which has a javascript compiler built into the program. I have node.js installed but I cannot seem to use the `require` function. Any recommendations on how one might include those modules into the application?

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require()` is a function built into the node.js environment.  It is not part of standard Javascript and thus is likely not present in your other Javascript environment.  Keep in mind that lots of modules written for node.js use node.js specific functions and modules that would not necessarily be present in some other JS engine.

If you tell us more about what JS engine you are running and what you're trying to accomplish in that engine with node.js modules, we might be able to make more specific recommendations for how to proceed.  Unless this other JS engine is attempting to be 100% compatible with the node.js environment or unless the modules are you attempting to use don't reference any of the features that are specific to the node.js environment, it is unlikely those modules will run in this other JS environment.

Keep in mind that node.js is a V8 Javascript engine plus a whole bunch of other libraries and features.  You can't just replace it with just a Javascript engine.

Comment: Only information I could find about the javascript in the application was javascript API v7.2.  Not sure if that is the engine or something else. 


Is there any way I could call my node script from the application causing it to run outside the application.  Something like node myScript.js?

Comment: In the Application I want to run my script prior to performing a task and there is an option to do that in the application. My script is querying a database and writing the results to a .txt file.  I just need the .txt file to be present before performing the task.

Comment: @ESco - What is the application that contains this other implementation of Javascript?  What product is it?